# How does ASP.NET MVC invoke different controller when URL never changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In [this Adding a Controller (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-controller) tutorial I read:

> ASP.NET MVC invokes different controller classes (and different action
>   methods within them) depending on the **incoming URL**

However, I am looking now at the source code full of such Controllers, the web app is fully functional, switches from Controller to Controller smoothly, **without ever changing the URL**...

How does this work?

Comment: How do you know it switches? Are you tracing it? Are there Ajax calls in the JavaScript? Those won't change the URL on the browser but will request a different URL from the server.

Comment: @DonO Good point, thank you. Yes, I am tracing it. Yes, there are Ajax calls in the JavaScript (both directly and through jQuery). Is that the key to the mystery?

Comment: @dapts Most likely, you can see the urls on those ajax calls and if they contain the names of the other controllers that are called than you should have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, based on method, so one action might handle `POST` requests because it is decorated with `[HttpPost]` attribute and another one for `GET` requests as it is decorated with `[HttpGet]` attribute

I need to do some more guesswork as you've not detailed your observation: your application might send `AJAX` requests, and while the `Url` of the page is not changing, different actions in controllers are invoked because of these behind the scene requests.

Comment: I think it is your second point: "my" application *is* sending AJAX requests. I now have to figure out how does that work. Thanks +1.